# Why does the number 01000 convert to 512?

Tags: go, struct

I started to learn Go a few days ago and while learning about `structs` I came across and instance where I wanted to create a contacts structure and the zip code of 01000 was printed to the terminal as 512 instead on 01000

Here is the block of code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type contactInfo struct {
    email   string
    zipCode int
}

type person struct {
    firstName string
    lastName  string
    contact   contactInfo
}

func main() {
    jim := person{
        firstName: "Jim",
        lastName:  "Party",
        contact:   contactInfo{email: "jim.party@gmail.com", zipCode: 01000},
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", jim)
}
```

Here is the output to the terminal :

```
{firstName:Jim lastName:Party contact:{email:jim.party@gmail.com zipCode:512}}%
```

I used the command `go run main.go` and was expecting 01000 as the zip code but I got 512.

Comment: Please, don't treat zipcodes or phone numbers as (mathematical) numbers! Use strings to represent them!

Comment: note that a leading 0 is interpreted as octal in many languages, so this isn't going to be unique to Go.

Answer (score 6):

Because the `0` prefix indicates octal. We can read about this in [Go spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Integer_literals):

> ```
> octal_lit      = "0" [ "o" | "O" ] [ "_" ] octal_digits .
> ```

So the literal string `01000` is interpreted as 1 * 8^3 + 0 * 8^2 + 0 * 8^1 + 0 * 8^0 = 512.

As of [Go 1.13](https://go.dev/doc/go1.13), you can (and probably "should") use the convention of `0o` instead of `0`, when you intend to use octal, for improved readability.  That is to say, it would be better to write `0o1000`, as that is more visually distinct and clear that octal was intended.

---

In your specific case, you should treat zip codes as strings, not as numbers.